# django - embedding variables within tags

Tags: python, django

Using pycharm Django.  I am passing a dictionary "myDict":

```
{'id': 1, 'abvName': 'xyz', 'Name': 'ABCDEF'}
```

I would like to use a template statement which requires the id value as follows:

```
<a href="{% url 'detail' recId= {{ myDict.id }} %}">" Get id Rec
```

But apparently, I can’t embed a tag or a variable within a tag. I can pass the id separately from views.py but maybe I am missing a better way to do this accessing the dictionary.

Comment: Can you try to be more clear with some code example ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to understand how to format your post properly.

Comment: Try `{% url 'detail' recId=myDict.id %}` you don't need the `{{` and `}}` when you refer variables inside a template tag (`{% some_tag ... %}`)

Comment: Thank you Abdul! That does work.